# Snapd consuming bandwidth from time to time

Tags: snap, bandwidth

I didn't install any snap package so for, but sometimes the snapd process is using the bandwidth. Is this activity normal ? What is the snap deamon downloading ?

`snap list` returns :

```
Name  Version  Rev   Developer  Notes

core  16-2     1264  canonical  -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periodically snapd will check to see if there are any updates to installed snaps (including the core snap you have installed).

Comment: humm, I don't recoll installing it, is it safe to remove it ?

Comment: snapd is preinstalled in the images. As long as you aren't using any snaps (other than core), you're safe to remove it.

Comment: is it safe to kill the process?